# Entity Framework Data Annotations not working for [Table("")] in differnet languages?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have some customers that are having issues with our application because it is looking at the wrong table name.

To give you a little history we used to have a Users table that was named "Users" in the database. In a newer version we changed this table to "cp_Users". We put a [Table("cp_Users")] attribute on the class and updated the migration to rename the table:

```
[Table("cp_Users")]
    public partial class Users
    {

RenameTable(name: "dbo.Users", newName: "cp_Users");
```

Now the only difference between my environment and these other two environments is the language. My system is in english and their system is in Swedish (SQL is Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS)

Am I doing this wrong or could this be a bug? Why does the code for them still look for the "Users" table and not "cp_Users"

Comment: So I found out it is partially working. What is happening is it is able to READ from the cp_Users table but when db.SaveChanges() is called it is looking for the table "Users" instead of "cp_Users"

Comment: I got a copy of the problem database and put it on a English system and it doesn't seem to have the problem. However it was a completely different system (same database) so it may not be the culture... just stating what I found during my troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out and it had nothing to do with Entity. I found out that there was an old trigger left on the table which was still pointing to the old table name.

Apparently entity can pickup trigger errors when updating the tables.